# Blender is only rendering a composite of a movie clip that I made and not the full scene, which I want it to

Tags: rendering, scene, compositing-nodes

I am trying to render a scene, but when I render I'm only rendering the keyed footage that I composited initially in the project. Please refer to this [video link](https://youtu.be/zzTIBQsDoC4) where I show my project and break down the issue more in-depth.

The gist is: I want to render a scene that has more objects and an HDRI added, but Blender is only rendering a composited video clip.

Comment: Hello and welcome, next time would be better if you show more info here in your post than using a link, the problem that you have  is that you don't have a Render Layer Node for the compositor to render your scene [Here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/input/render_layers.html)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation by verbally describing your issue, don't just post, images, videos, files to download, or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2):

This is  the expected behaviour: if in the post processing tab compositor and sequencer are checked, the output will be overwritten by what is resulting in the compositor and sequencer windows.

So, to solve, uncheck thoose options or create in the compositor a render layer input and plug it in the compositor output node.

Be sure that no video sequence is in the VSE window also (or it will overwrite the output if checked in the post processing tab).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the compositor un-check the "use nodes" inside compositing, or composite your scene instead of the tiff sequence man

[image]